# Application of Bernouli's Theorem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-dynamics, bernoulli-equation

[image]

We have to calculate the velocity of efflux in this problem. My issue is, when I apply Bernoulli about the open end of  the fluid and a point just outside the orifice, I seem to get a different answer than when I apply Bernoulli about a point just inside and just outside the orifice. Why is that? Can we not apply Bernoulli about the first set of points?

Comment: If that whole mechanism is spinning, then I think centrifugal potential comes in handy.  http://scienceworld.wolfram.com/physics/CentrifugalPotential.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can apply Bernoulli in both cases. My guess is that you haven't taken into account the centrifugal potential. The Bernoulli equation between the open end and the point just outside of the fluid becomes:

$\frac{p_A}{\rho}+\frac{v_a^2}{2}+gz_a-\frac{r_a^2\omega^2}{2}=\frac{p_e}{\rho}+\frac{v_e^2}{2}+gz_e-\frac{r_e^2\omega^2}{2}$

$z_a=z_e$ - gravity doesn't play a role

$r_a=l-h$ - the radius for the open end

$r_e=l$ - the radius for the exit

$p_A=p_e=p_0$ - the pressure equals the ambient pressure (the effect of the air rotating in the first half of the pipe can be neglected here)

$v_a=0$

You can write the same equation for the point just inside of the orifice. The difference would be that there the pressure is not $p_0$, but $p_0+\frac{r_e^2\omega^2}{2}-\frac{r_a^2\omega^2}{2}$ due to an other Bernoulli between this point and the point at the open end.

The result would be the same:

$v_e=\sqrt{\frac{l^2\omega^2}{2}-\frac{(l-h)^2\omega^2}{2}}$

Comment: Actually I haven't been introduced to centrifugal potential, so what would be a good source to learn the same?

Comment: Actually I have learned the fundamentals of fluid mechanics from my Hungarian textbook. That wouldn't help you. After some quick searching I found this link that might be helpful: 
http://paoc.mit.edu/labweb/notes/chap6.pdf

I think this concept is actually included in almost every basic fluid mechanics textbook. The surface of the rotating fluid is a standard example.